# How useful is ionice tool with modern linux kernel

Tags: kernel, io, ionice

Ionice tool is supposed to offer relieve on high I/O load by executing commands only when system is in specified state.

https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/ionice.html states

> Linux supports I/O scheduling priorities and classes since 2.6.13 with the CFQ I/O scheduler.

However CFQ I/O has been deprecated and removed from kernel since 5.3

So what is the state of this utility? Does it actually work at all on modern kernels?

Additional piece of information

ionice uses kernel call `ioprio_set`

https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioprio_set.2.html

The documentation states:

> These system calls have an effect only when used in conjunction with an I/O scheduler that supports I/O priorities.  As at kernel 2.6.17 the only such scheduler is the Completely Fair Queuing (CFQ) I/O scheduler.

Comment: In my humble opinion, reducing the priority of a long-term CPU-intensive process can be very useful. This allows the system to perform other tasks such as compressing backups, without compromising performance. However, please note that only one scheduler is removed and it doesn't affect the tool itself, as far as I can recall.

Comment: As far as I understand ionice expects CFQ for it to work at all,otherwise it does nothing

Comment: i think this question would be due its specificaltallity more suitable for unix.se where the *nix gurus are sitting. ( [unix.se] ) don't get me wrong, but I flagged this question for movement due I am interested to get the right answer on that :)